# Random Circular Route Generator

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3, path-finding

I'm trying to design an algorithm that will allow a user to define distance in meters as an input parameter which then returns co-ordinates for a random circular route (from the users current location, returning back to the same location). The co-ordinates will be plotted using the Google Directions API and displayed back to the user as a route on Google maps.

Whilst I'm okay with plotting the co-ordinates once they've been generate, I'm still researching an optimal way of generating these co-ordinates in the first place.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this a problem that will require a novel solution?
2. If a novel solution is required does anyone have an ideas on how this could be achieved efficiently
   and accurately?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the input distance measure - how far the user goes (=diameter) or the length of the route (=circumference)? And do we need to worry about the curvature of the Earth, or about poles?

Comment: The input distance is the circumference in meters. The algorithm will be used to generate random running routes of relatively small distances so the initial assumption is that the curvature of the Earth is neglected and the user is located as if they wear near the equator...therefore currently approximating 113,300 meters in a degree when calculating latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Neglecting the curvature of the Earth and assuming the user is on the equator:

The first thing you need to do is pick a *random center* for your circle. The input location is on the circumference of the circle, so the center is 1 radius away in a random direction. So by picking a direction uniformly in random, we pick a the center uniformly in random.

```
radius = circumference/(2*pi)
direction = 2*pi*random()                      # random() is uniform between 0-1
center_x = user_x + radius*cos(direction)
center_y = user_y + radius*sin(direction)
```

Now you have both a radius and the center of the circle. You can generate points on the circumference by letting `angle` vary between 0 and 2pi, and for each angle you generate:

```
point_x = center_x + radius*cos(angle)
point_y = center_y + radius*sin(angle)
```

Hint: If you need to generate points starting with the user's location, instead of varying angle from 0 to 2pi, vary it from `direction - pi` to `direction + pi`. If you want to vary the direction of the movement along the circle (clockwise or ccw), vary the angle in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks Joni!

Helpful answer although I should have made this more clear in the original post that I'm looking for a route that returns to the users original location but is not an exact circle. I'll update below as I've been working on a solution that approximates this reasonably accurately.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that I've came up with so far is the following:

1. Generate a list of points around a circle in polar co-ordinates.The perimeter of the
   circle will be the distance of the route. The start/end point are located on the
   perimeter. Shown in the image below, the red point indicates the start and end point.

   [List of points around a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb7t0.png)
2. Apply random noise by subtracting a random number from the radius of each point on the
   circle. The random number will be between 0 and 80% of the radius to avoid
   the route skewing towards the centre.
3. Generate a polygon from the randomised polar co-ordinates.
4. Scale the randomised polygon so that the perimeter is the same as the
   original circle. See image below, blue line shows the original polygon generated, the
   green line shows the scaled version (perimeter approximately similar to the original
   circle).

   [Randomised polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ow9.png)
5. Haven't implemented this yet but will then convert the co-ordinates of each point to
   latitude and longitude, plotting the route using the Google Directions API.

Here's a sample of the code I used to implement this:

```
numberOfEdges = 20  # Number of edges on polygon
radius =  1  # Radius (polar co-ordinates)
deltaTheta = (2 * math.pi) / numberOfEdges  # Change in angle per point (polar co-ordinates)

# For each delta theta defining a list of X and Y co-ordinates for the unit circle polygon and
# generating a random polygon by varying the radius  
currentTheta = 0
coordsPolygon = [[1, 0]] 
coordsRandomPolygon = [[1, 0]]
perimeterPolygon = 0
perimeterRandomPolygon = 0
randomRadiusLst = []
for i in range(numberOfEdges):    
    currentTheta += deltaTheta
    randomRadius = radius - random.uniform(0, (0.8 * radius))
    randomRadiusLst.append(randomRadius)

    if (i ==  (numberOfEdges - 1)):
        coordsPolygon.append([1, 0])
        coordsRandomPolygon.append([1, 0])
    else:
        coordsPolygon.append([radius * math.cos(currentTheta), radius * math.sin(currentTheta)])
        coordsRandomPolygon.append([randomRadius * math.cos(currentTheta), randomRadius * math.sin(currentTheta)])

    # Distance between points for unit circle polygon and random polygon 
    perimeterPolygon += math.sqrt((coordsPolygon[i][0]-coordsPolygon[i-1][0])**2 + (coordsPolygon[i][1]-coordsPolygon[i-1][1])**2) 
    perimeterRandomPolygon += math.sqrt((coordsRandomPolygon[i][0]-coordsRandomPolygon[i-1][0])**2 + (coordsRandomPolygon[i][1]-coordsRandomPolygon[i-1][1])**2)


# Scaling the random polygon to the perimeter of the original unit circle
scalingFactor = perimeterPolygon / perimeterRandomPolygon
currentTheta = 0
coordsRandomPolygonScaled = [[1, 0]]
perimeterScaledRandomPolygon = 0
for i in range(numberOfEdges):
    currentTheta += deltaTheta
    if (i ==  (numberOfEdges - 1)):
        coordsRandomPolygonScaled.append([1, 0])
    else:
        coordsRandomPolygonScaled.append([(randomRadiusLst[i] * scalingFactor) * math.cos(currentTheta), (randomRadiusLst[i] * scalingFactor) * math.sin(currentTheta)])

    perimeterScaledRandomPolygon += math.sqrt((coordsRandomPolygonScaled[i][0]-coordsRandomPolygonScaled[i-1][0])**2 + (coordsRandomPolygonScaled[i][1]-coordsRandomPolygonScaled[i-1][1])**2)
```